# How much times per day my app can post to users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

have my appid and secret key from facebook and i just making some test with one acount that i create just a week ago, yesterday i started to make test posting with that account and just working fine (im using the FacebookAPI.cs dll), but suddenly today after 10 post i can do it anymore, I test with two diferent accounts and just work fine, so i think that there's a limit of post per day to a user wall or something similar, anyone knows that limit or the time that has to pass until i can make post in That account again? 
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to execute the same POST request(same content) itself frequently? If so facebook will block the request cosidering it as a spam. No specific values were found in Facebook Graph documentation.

But something like 600 requests per 600 sec is found in the facebook developer forum (not a verified value)

Reference : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56950

Comment: Thanks for answer robin, i think is for that reason i repeated some posts (just for testing) , so im going to change the content of my post the way that everyone are different, doing this is supposed to work? ill try it.

Comment: To confirm it i just tried posting content with slight changes like "test content1","test content2" etc in a for loop with 10 iteration. only few got posted. i almost feel that not more than 1 request will get processed in a second from 1 ip. And also if you try posting the same content the exception arising is "Duplicate status message"

Comment: Ok, i managed to continue with my tests :D , just by clicking the like button in every post, cool.